Good to have a packed tourist like itinerary when considering for Japan's visitor visa?
I have a small doubt:
Is it a right thing to be travelling around places when you are applying for a visitor visa?
I am planning to visit my friend in Japan, and for the same I will be applying for a visitor visa from India.
My question is that is it a legit thing to be travelling across cities when it comes to visitor visa?
Or
Is visit visa generally meant for cases when the visitor just mostly stays at the inviter's residence(maybe for a function/event?) and roam around locally little bit.
I am confused on how it works when it comes to a visitor visa.
I need to decide on my itinerary for travel basis on this same question.
Should I have a tourist-like itinerary for my trip where I roam around cities, showing different hotel accommodations, etc.
Or Should I just stay at my friend's residence and can just trip around locally.
I am fixated on the fact that I will be applying for a visitor visa. Why? Because that's what my main purpose actually is- to visit my friend. But how will the course of my trip actually be is something I am unable to decide.
Some people told me that both tourist visa and visitor visa allow the visa applicant to tour. But few suggested that visitor visa is for special occasions/meeting friends and not for travelling around.
Request you to kindly take out your few minutes and share your experiences on this question!
Would be a great help, really.
Thanks in advance!

Having a great itinerary is not a guarantee of success. Your previous questions are basically pretty similar to this one. IMHO you need to stop paying attention to what ‘some people’ tell you. Just look at the official visa eligibility criteria and documentary requirements, apply if you believe you meet them, don’t apply if you are doubtful.

@Traveller, yes, I got your point !

Applying as a visitor means as a visitor for the country, not just for your friend, at least for countries where the government has no objections to a legitimately present foreigner moving around.
To avoid any potential misunderstanding, you can mention as purpose of your visit both visiting a friend and tourism.
If you look at the Japanese Ministry of Foreign Affairs, you can read:

Short-Term Stay: A stay of up to 90 days for tourism, business, visiting friends or relatives, etc. that does not include remunerative activities.


Okay, have a touristy visit then! Thanks.
